# PageContentViewController Swift galeria de imágenes

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Hola en mi aplicación tengo una galería de imágenes con un **PageContentViewController**, en este caso carga un arreglo de imágenes de un lugar en especifico ya que es una aplicación de turismo  la estructura de mi aplicacion es toda similar por lo tanto necesito que desde otra pantalla cargue otro arreglo de imágenes con la misma estructura. en este caso la base está, lo que necesito saber es como enviarle desde otra pantalla un arreglo distinto para que se vea otro grupo de imágenes. Adjunto código del controlador y el page content.

PageContentViewController:

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var pageIndex: Int = 0
    var strTitle: String?
    var strPhotoName: String?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.strPhotoName!)
        //lblTitle.text = self.strTitle!
    }
}
```

ViewController2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()
    var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = NSArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrPageTitle = ["This is The App Guruz", "This is Table Tennis 3D", "This is Hide Secrets","4","5","6"];
        arrPagePhoto = ["madero1", "madero2", "madero3","madero5","madero6","madero7"];

        self.dataSource = self

        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK:- UIPageViewControllerDataSource Methods

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
        {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1;
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        index += 1;
        if (index == arrPageTitle.count)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    // MARK:- Other Methods
    func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController
    {
        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
        pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

        return pageContentViewController
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás reinicializando tus arrays en `viewDidLoad`, con lo que aunque intentes asignarle nuevos valores a las variables de tus arrays desde otros controladores, en `viewDidLoad` los estás machacando...

En lugar de inicializar los arrays en viewDidLoad con esos literales, hazlo en la declaración de las variables:

```
class ViewController2: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    var arrPageTitle: NSArray = ["This is The App Guruz", "This is Table Tennis 3D", "This is Hide Secrets","4","5","6"]
    var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = ["madero1", "madero2", "madero3","madero5","madero6","madero7"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self

        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    ...

}
```

y así cuando inicialices el controlador desde otro sitio, puedes hacer:

```
let vc = ViewController2()
vc.arrPageTitle = ["mi nueva foto 1", "mi nueva foto 2"]
vc.arrPagePhoto = ["nueva-foto-1", "nueva-foto-2"]
```

y te debería coger los nuevos valores creados